# With React-Select, how can I make the dropdown accessible through a React-Bootstrap-Glyphicon?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-select

I wanted to create a dropdown using React-Select, but instead of the UI looking like this:[image]

I wanted it to look like this:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
dropDown = R.createElement(Select, {
            options: options,
            valueKey: 'value',
            labelKey: 'name',
            clearable: false,
            placeholder: "Action",
            searchable: false,
            autosize: false,
            onChange: function (opt) {
                if (opt.callback === undefined && opt.callback !== "function") { return; }
                opt.callback({
                    importable: importable,
                    scheduledImportable: sImportable
                }, index);
            },
            optionRenderer: function (ele) {
                return R.createElement(
                            'span',
                            { style: { color: ele.color} },
                            R.createElement('span', { className: ele.icon},null, " "),
                            ele.name
                        );
            }
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok to use another element to help?

```
<div className="select-wrapper">
  <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <Select .... />
</div>
```

Then css

```
.select-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}

.select-wrapper .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  top: 7px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```